# Reducer function changing the state, but screen not re-rendering

Tags: javascript, react-native

In my React Native app set up with Android Studio, I'm using redux-persist to persist the state, storage engine is AsyncStorage. In the app I have an 'add' button and a 'remove' button which adds and removes an item from the state.

The 'add' button works fine, it adds an item to the state and the screen gets re-rendered.
But the 'remove' button though removes an item from the state (I've seen it on React Native Debugger), it does not re-render the screen and persist the state. But a different version of the code works.

I want to know why the former version does not work. Here is my reducer function:

```
//reducer.js

import React from 'react';

const initialState = {
    key: [
        { id: 0 },
        { id: 1 }
    ]
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {

    switch (action.type) {
        case 'SAVE':
            return { key: [...state.key, action.payload] };

        // this version doesn't re-render the screen and doesn't persist
        case 'REMOVE':
            let { key } = state;
            key.pop();
            return { key };
        
        // this version re-renders the screen and persists
        case 'REMOVE':
            let { key } = state;
            return { key : key.slice(0, key.length - 1)};

        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export { reducer };
```

And here are my **store.js**, **main.js**, **App.js** and dependencies:

```
// store.js

import React from 'react';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
import { reducer } from './reducer';

const persistConfig = {
    key: 'abc',
    storage: AsyncStorage
};

const pReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducer);

let store = createStore(
    pReducer,
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
);

let persistor = persistStore(store);

export { store, persistor };


// main.js

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { ScrollView, View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

const Main = () => {

    let key = useSelector(state => state.key);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

    const add = () => {
        dispatch({ type: "SAVE", payload: { id: key.length } });
    }

    const remove = () => {
        dispatch({ type: "REMOVE" });
    }

    const load = () => {
        setShow(true);
    }

    const items = key.map((item) => <Text key={item.id}>{item.id}</Text>);

    return (
        <ScrollView>
            <View>
                <Button
                    title='add'
                    onPress={add}
                />
                <Button
                    title='remove'
                    onPress={remove}
                />
                <Button
                    title='load'
                    onPress={load}
                />
                {show ? <Text>your state contains {key.length} items</Text> : <Text></Text>}
            </View>
            <View>
                {items}
            </View>
        </ScrollView>
    );
};

export default Main;


// App.js

import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { store, persistor } from './store';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react';
import Main from './main';

const App = () => {

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
      <Main/>
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  );
};

export default App;


//package.json

"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.12.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.7.3",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.9.0",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "0.63.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.8.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.13.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.1.8",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.11.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.8.4",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^1.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^25.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.5.1",
    "jest": "^25.1.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.59.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.13.1"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The former doesn't work because you're mutating the array.

Consider the following snippets:

```js
const bla = {
  key: [1, 2]
};

let {
  key
} = bla;

key.pop();

console.log(key);
console.log(bla);
```

```js
const bla = {
  key: [1, 2]
};
let {
  key
} = bla;

console.log(key.slice(0, key.length - 1));
console.log(bla)
```

Notice how `console.log(bla)` logs different values as `pop` modifies the array whereas `slice` creates a new array.

Comment: I thought when I was doing this: let { key } = state; I was declaring a new variable key with content state.key, so I thought mutating the newly formed variable will not be an issue. Now that I run your code snippet, I see where I'm mistaken. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You need to clone that array then modify it, you tried to mutate the original one.

See from the documentations of [`.pop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) and [`.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

> The slice() method returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array into a new array object selected from start to end (end not included) where start and end represent the index of items in that array. The original array will not be modified.

> The pop method removes the last element from an array and returns that value to the caller.

So basically that's why `.slice()` is working and `.pop()` doesn't in this case.

Comment: let { key } = state;  key.pop();  return { key }; I thought this creates a new variable key with the value state.key, does that not happen? I am aware of the difference between pop() and slice().